# how to change OrderReceipt in odoo 14

Tags: odoo, point-of-sale, odoo-14, pos

I'm trying to edit the client order receipt at the cashier, so I tried to inherit it and change its content like this: I created a new module, added an xml file in qweb list in manifest, and wrote this in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
<t t-name="custom_order_receipt" t-inherit="point_of_sale.OrderReceipt" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='pos-receipt']" position="replace">
        <div> Hello</div>
    </xpath>
</t>
```

But this changed nothing on the receipt, I still have the default content.
Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with my code is that I have pointed on the class in the wrong way, when I changed like this it worked fine : `div[hasclass('pos-receipt')]`, I found the solution searching on odoo source code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="custom_order_receipt" t-inherit="point_of_sale.OrderReceipt" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('pos-receipt')]" position="replace">
            <div> Hello</div>
        </xpath>
    </t>
```